# LInq to Sql Insert DateTime problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I’m getting started on Linq to sql. I am trying to insert a record. Here is my code.

```
FMCSA_USER_LOG _MyUserLog = new FMCSA_USER_LOG();

_MyUserLog.USER_ID = model.UserID;

_MyUserLog.ACTIVITY_TYPE_ID = model.ActivityTypeID;
_MyUserLog.ACTIVITY_TARGET =  model.ActivityTarget;
_MyUserLog.DESCRIPTION = model.Description;
_MyUserLog.ACTIVITY_TIME = DateTime.Today;
_MyUserLog.ACTIVITY_TYPE_ID = null;
_MyUserLog.DESCRIPTION = null;
db.FMCSA_USER_LOGs.InsertOnSubmit(_MyUserLog);

db.SubmitChanges();
```

I received this exception on the SubmitChanges:

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between
>   1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999
>   11:59:59 PM.

From my reading of this problem, it occurs when you have a date field and it is set to too low a value. Yet the only date field in the table I set to today’s date.

Here is the record; I don’t see what I’m doing wrong.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FMCSA_USER_LOG](
 [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [USER_ID] [int] NULL,
 [ACTIVITY_TIME] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
 [ACTIVITY_TYPE_ID] [int] NULL,
 [ACTIVITY_TARGET] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [DESCRIPTION] [varchar](8000) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FMCSA_USER_LOG] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 ([ID] ASC)
)
```

Comment: Did you change your database model and have not updated your Linq-to-SQL model to reflect those changes?? A Linq-to-SQL model does not update automatically - it's a snapshot of the database structures at a given time - if you change it in the database later on, you need to update your model, too - explicitly.

Comment: Are you sure that there is not another `datetime` column in place somewhere (maybe a trigger)? The column in the given script is `datetime2` and thus should actually match the range of .NET's `System.DateTime` IMO, so that the value that you set from .NET should not be too high or too low for the database.

Comment: What is the ACTIVITY_TIME field seen as in the dbml file, "Server Data Type" and "Type"?

Comment: @Bob Avallone: Just a tip, do a GetChangeSet() where you do your SubmitChanges() and some "for each"s on your Insert and Modify to find which records are erroneous. From there, you'll see what's the problem. Whenever I had this type of error, the problem was me! Sure it's a shot in the dark, but it takes 5mins to do, and you clear a possibility.

Comment: Have you turned on the logging on the datacontext to see what is being submitted?

Comment: @Bob Avallone: DATETIME2 has a date range of "0001 / 01 / 01" through "9999 / 12 / 31" while the DATETIME type only supports year 1753-9999. Looking at the exception, seems like something is trying to set a datetime not datetime2 value in some other table not FMCSA_USER_LOG

Comment: The use of Tipx's comment help me figure the problem which was that the submitchanges triggered the insert plus two inserts that I did earlier. However, I just found out that Linq to SQL does not support Oracle. We are planning to move to Oracle so I plan to look into Entity Framework 4. If you, Tipx, put your comment as a reply instead of a comment, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: I'd run enterprise manager and look at the actual trace of what is going to sqlserver. that will nail the problem quickly is my guess.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to shoehorn a .net datetime into a datetime2 column.
I got it working with this method:

```
FMCSA_USER_LOG _MyUserLog = new FMCSA_USER_LOG();

var MyAwesomeDateTime = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff");
var MyAwesomeDateTime2 = DateTime.ParseExact(MyAwesomeDateTime , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

_MyUserLog.USER_ID = model.UserID;

_MyUserLog.ACTIVITY_TYPE_ID = model.ActivityTypeID;
_MyUserLog.ACTIVITY_TARGET =  model.ActivityTarget;
_MyUserLog.DESCRIPTION = model.Description;
_MyUserLog.ACTIVITY_TIME = MyAwesomeDateTime2;
_MyUserLog.ACTIVITY_TYPE_ID = null;
_MyUserLog.DESCRIPTION = null;
db.FMCSA_USER_LOGs.InsertOnSubmit(_MyUserLog);

db.SubmitChanges();
```